# How to show the image on the left and the content on the right using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement list/grid toggle. I have the grid and I'm trying to toggle to list, so I'd like to show the images on the left side and the content on the right side.

HTML code:

```
<div class="card infinite-item">
  <div class="img-dimension">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/media/category/img.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">idea 01</h5>
    <div class="card-text">        
          <p>Phasellus a est. Nam eget dui. Pellentesque ut neque. Nunc sed turpis. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi.</p>        
    </div>
    <div class="text-left pb-2 pt-2">
        <a id="idea_detail_1" href="/idea/1/">Details...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right card-icons">
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">Discussion</span>
      <a class="like badge">
        like button        
      </a>
      <a class="dislike badge">
        dislike button
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="badge comments">
        comments
      </a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="card-footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

I didn't change the CSS, so it's the bootstrap default CSS code:

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
}

.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-title {
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
```

Comment: use `float:left` and `float:right` on the element divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; /* optional */
}
```

You can change `flex-direction: column` to `flex-direction: row` in order to achieve your question.

Comment: It works. But I have the footer as well (I edited the question to show it) and it keeps on the rigth side.

Comment: You can insert the `<div class="card-footer">` inside of `<div class="card-body">` just right before its closing tag but it would have a right and bottom padding. You can remove this by changing the values of `.card-body`'s padding to: `padding: 1.25rem 0 0 1.25rem`

Answer (score 1):

```
.card-img-top {
width: 100%;
border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
position: relative;
left: 0;
display: inline-block
```

}

```
.card-body {
flex: 1 1 auto;
padding: 1.25rem;
position: relative;
right: 0;
display: inline-block;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

use column for this,for example:

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
------------your content here-------------
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
------------your Image here---------------
</div>
</div>
```